# i have an text file with size 10MB and i want to split the text file into 2 equal size (5MB each) partition

Tags: scala

I have a text file with size 10MB and I want to split the text file into 2 equal size (5MB each) partition by size in scala. Is there a way we can do partition the text file by size?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried thus far?  Include code or segments thereof if possible

Answer (score 1):

`rdd.repartition(2)` will shuffle the data into 2 partitions, It will use the default hash partitioner which will probably not get you exactly equal sizes but close enough.

10MB is already very small though, I wouldn't worry too much about partitioning the file.

If you goal is to simply split the file consider using the command line tool `split` instead of writing your own program to do it.

Comment: Thank you. but if i want to partition by required size like i would like to set that what ever the size of my file that i received and when i done the partition on that file the size of the each file must be 2MB( should not exceed more than that).. is it possible to set the file size dynamically ?